# Correct encoding for XML file read from stdin

Tags: python

Consider I need to read an XML file from `stdin`. How do I get the encoding right?

Currently I simply do

```
xmlString = sys.stdin.read()
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xmlString)
```

Apparently `xmlString` is not always properly decoded resulting in misinterpreted characters.

Is there a possibility to fix this or do I have to live with what I get from `stdin` "as is"?

**Edit:**
It's save to assume that the file provided via `stdin` is an SVG file with proper XML declaration, e.g. consider

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <desc>ú</desc>
</svg>
```

That means the `encoding` attribute can be used to detect encoding (but obviously I have to read at least the first line for that) and afterwards I would have to somehow adjust reading from `stdin` using the detected encoding.

Comment: Could you provide some example showing your problem's symtomps?

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3? Are you piping in the file? If piping, the encoding may not be knowable unless the first line is a declaration line or there is some fancy microsoft BOM encoding. Perhaps assume its utf-8 with a command line parameter for other encodings?

Comment: For the time being let's assume Python 3 (Python 2 compatibility is planned in the long run but let's not over-complicate things just now)

Comment: As an example I'm piping a file encoded as UTF-8 on the Windows command line. File content: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><desc>ú</desc></svg>`

The decoded content I receive with stdin.read() parses the `ú` as `Ãº`

Comment: @EduardBraun Is it an option to use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) which detects the encoding for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was most easy in this case. With

```
try:
    input = sys.stdin.buffer
except AttributeError:
    input = sys.stdin

xmlString = input.read()
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xmlString)
```

`stdin` is opened as a binary stream (i.e. not decoded). In my particular case the XML parser handles the decoding on its own just fine, making any effort from my side unnecessary.

Note that Python 3 opens `stdin` in text mode (decoded) by default but obviously with the wrong character encoding in many cases. Therefore the `buffer` attribute is necessary to access the underlying binary stream.
The exception handling is necessary because this is the default behavior in earlier versions of Python and the `buffer` attribute is not available.

Answer (score 0):

If the file encoding could be different each time, and it's completely unknown, you could use [`chardet` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) to guess it's encoding. Note that it uses some statistical data to find the best match so it's no perfect.

If you know the encoding of your data, you have two options. The [`PYTHONIOENCODING` variable](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING), or using [`str.decode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode).